# How can one obtain rep on Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

Complete makeover:

I am committed to two proposals on Area 51, and I have 151 rep.  Unfortunately, I cannot increase the weight of my commitment by gaining rep, because I cannot create example questions in those two proposals - they are in the commitment stage.

My question is, is it possible to get more rep without having to do anything in other proposals?

Answer (score 2):

As reported in the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), the reputation is changed basing on the following events:

- Proposal is followed or committed to: +5
- Question is voted as on- or off-topic: +5
- Question is voted as bad example question: -2
- Referred user with a confirmed email address commits to the proposal  +5
- Follow through on your commitment: +50
- Referred user with a confirmed email address follows through on their commitment: +25

The first point is referring to your own proposals; when a user follow them, your reputation increases of 5 points.
The fifth point is referring to the proposals that you follow until they become a public site; this means you followed a proposal, committed to it, and participated to the site during the beta phase.

Comment: I changed my question - it wasn't clear.

Comment: Sounds like you need to refer a lot of users and have them follow through on their commitments!

Answer (score 1):

The weight of your commitment depends on your total reputation across the whole Stack Exchange network. So by participating in other sites and gaining reputation on those you can increase your commitment weight on Area 51.

I don't know whether you weight updates continually or whether it's a one off calculation when you sign up.

Comment: I changed my question - it wasn't clear.

Comment: @drm65 - I changed my answer ;)

Comment: OK, so I have a pretty good weight then, right?  My flair has 5.5K.  That's comforting.  I thought the weight has determined by only A51 rep, which didn't make sense to me.